# Probably of Nuclear War happening within the next 500 yrs = 99.72%???

Tags: probability

Was doing a project and wondering whether this makes sense:

So basically this article by a professor named Alex says that the chance per year of a nuclear war is 1.17%. If we extrapolate this over 500 years, does that make the chance of a nuclear war occurring sometime within the next 500 years 99.82%? (Since [100-1.17]^500 is approximately 99.72%).

It just seemed pretty interesting to me that the number came out that high. It actually ended up not mattering for the project, but if anyone could explain whether the logic works or not they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The logic does work. We can only hope Alex was wrong.

Comment: @URL The logic does not actually work: see my post.

Comment: A model like this will always have probability approach one after a sufficiently large time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem . Also the war will happen infinitely many times. Clearly there are some issues with extrapolating some professor named Alex's offhand estimate of how likely war is next year out 500 years, all while assuming independence. (Can we really say the probability of nuclear war next year is the same as it was in 1963, recent events notwithstanding?)

Comment: A nuclear war will not happen infinitely many times. There are only finitely many times a nuclear war can happen before everyone is either dead, or weakened by radiation sickness or injury.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning only applies if the probability of a nuclear war remains constant over $500$ years.

For example, if countries take steps to destroy their nuclear weapons, the chance of a nuclear war will decrease. Conversely, if a major conflict breaks out, the chance of a nuclear war in the following years will increase, increasing the probability of a nuclear war happening within $500$ years.

This is why you should be careful about using statistics/probability to estimate the chance of real-world events since they are often messy and unpredictable. For something like rolling a $6$ on a dice, the probability is still $1$ in $6$ and you can apply this logic to the situation.

Comment: If we’re being realistic, then the biggest point of contention is how they arrived at the probability in the first place, given that nuclear war has never been seen, nor do we have any sensible priors to validate the percent chance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to turn percentage into probability by dividing by 100.
Indeed, let's hope that Alex was wrong otherwise there's a 50% chance that we face a nuclear war during the next 60 years :
$$ p_{60} = 1 -(\frac{100-1.17}{100})^{60}\simeq 0.5064$$
That's 50.64%.

As for original question, one indeed gets 
$$ p_{500} = 1 -(\frac{100-1.17}{100})^{500}\simeq 0.9972$$
ie 99.72%

The reason why this probability increases so quickly is that the probability there's NO nuclear war is the next n years is $(\frac{100-1.17}{100})^{n}$. At first, that decreases by approximately 0.08 (ie 8%) every 10 years!